# Rotate the viewport camera around x- and y-axis instead of x- and z-axis

Tags: interface, camera

When I press the middle mouse button and move the mouse, the viewport camera in Blender rotates around both the x- and z-axis, i.e. it pitches (x-axis) and rolls (z-axis).

From other 3D programs I'm much more used to the approach where the axis horizontal to the screen is x, vertical in respect to the screen is y and from the screen towards the user is z. The viewport camera in such software then rotates around the x-axis (pitch) and y-axis (yaw).

Is there a way to configure Blender's viewport camera to rotate around the x- and y- axes instead of x and z?